# CSS: Three-column layout with a semi-fluid center

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm attempting to create a basic 3-column layout.  Essentially the center column should be fluid in that it should expand to consume any space not used by the left and right columns.  However, it also needs to have a fixed `min-width` of approximately 378 pixels.

There are a number of options for creating a 3-column layout with a completely fluid center column, [with](http://www.webdesign.org/img_articles/8033/demo_1.htm) or [without](http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/ykAPM/) using floats.  However, the problem with every prepackaged solution I've come across so far (as well as the ones I've tried myself) is that as the page width is decreased the right column will come over the top of the center column once the page gets too narrow.

I'd like to prevent this, if possible.  Ideally once the `min-width` is hit the right column should stay where it is, and the page should become horizontally scrollable.  So the goal is:

1. A 3-column layout with a fluid center column and fixed-width left and right columns.
2. A center column with a fixed minimum width to prevent it from becoming too small.
3. A right-column that respects the minimum width and does not trample, float over, or wrap below the center column when the window becomes too small.

A pure-CSS solution is preferred, but if there's a simple way to do this using some clever JavaScript I've got no objection to that approach either.

Comment: Umm... having exact-width left and right columns and a min-width on the center column is equivalent to having a `min-width` of (left+right+mincenter) on the entire three-column structure.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz - I tried exactly that, and it worked fine up until the point when I realized that the center div wasn't expanding to fill unused space on the page.  Trying to fix that caused all sorts of issues, but it could just be that I made a stupid error somewhere in the process.

Comment: Why not just make all three columns percentile width instead of having two fixed 50px columns outside?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

Comment: @FoolishSeth - Because then the left and right columns change width as the window is resized, which isn't the effect I'm after.  Only the center column should have a variable width.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this you can use **display:table** property. Write like this:

```
#wrapper{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper > div{
    display:table-cell;
    height:100%;
}

#left {
    width:50px;
    min-width:50px;
    background-color:pink;
}

#center {
    background-color:green;
    min-width:200px;
}

#right {
    width:50px;
    min-width:50px;
    background-color:red;
}

body, html{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ykAPM/137/

Comment: This works, except it introduced a [very nasty side-effect](http://terra.suncoastpc.com.au/cal.png) into my calendar widget.  That's just a standard jQuery.fullcalendar calendar.  It's positioned inside of the left column, if that makes a difference.  Any ideas?